Solaris 10: how to remove this tunnel?
This tunnel won't remove.
root@solaris10:~# ifconfig ip.6to4tun0 down   
ifconfig: setifflags: SIOCGLIFFLAGS: ip.6to4tun0: no such interface
root@solaris10:~# ifconfig ip.6to4tun0 unplumb
ifconfig: unplumb: SIOCGLIFFLAGS: ip.6to4tun0: no such interface

The short answer will be "it din't exist!" but..
root@solaris10:~# ifconfig -a|ggrep -A 11 6to4
ip.6to4tun0: flags=2200041<UP,RUNNING,NONUD,IPv6> mtu 65515 index 9
    inet tunnel src 192.168.0.1 
    tunnel hop limit 60 
    inet6 fe80::203:baff:fe50:cbe6/128 

The interface works
ping 192.168.0.1 
192.168.0.1 is alive

ping -A inet6 fe80::203:baff:fe50:cbe6    
fe80::203:baff:fe50:cbe6 is alive


Solution found
Those commands
ifconfig ip.6to4tun0 down   
ifconfig ip.6to4tun0 unplumb

are for ipv4
for ipv6 we must use this
fconfig ip.6to4tun0 inet6 unplumb

